# How to send model from parent to child

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have question about how to send model from parent to child using partial view and fancybox.

Here is my model

```
public class SampleHeaderViewModels
{
    [Display(Name = "ID")]
    public int intID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Field 1")]
    public string txtField1 { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Field 2")]
    public string txtField2 { get; set; }
}

public class SampleDetailViewModels
{
    [Display(Name = "ID")]
    public int intID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Line")]
    public int intLine { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Detail 1")]
    public string txtDetail1 { get; set; }
}

public class SampleViewModels
{
    public SampleHeaderViewModels Header { get; set; }
    public List<SampleDetailViewModels> Detail { get; set; }
    public SampleDetailViewModels OneDetai { get; set; }

    public SampleViewModels()
    {
        Header = new SampleHeaderViewModels();
        Detail = new List<SampleDetailViewModels>();
        OneDetai = new SampleDetailViewModels();
    }
}
```

Here is my Index View:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="block">
        <div class="block-content controls">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="row-form">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Header.txtField1, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Header.intID)
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Header.txtField1, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row-form">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Header.txtField2, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Header.txtField2, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="block">
        <div class="block-content controls">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="row-form">
                    <table id="tbDataTable" class="table table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Detail.FirstOrDefault().intLine)
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Detail.FirstOrDefault().txtDetail1)
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @if (Model.Detail != null)
                            {
                                foreach (var item in Model.Detail)
                                {
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.intLine)
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.txtDetail1)
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                }
                            }
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="row-form">
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <button type="button" id="btnAddDetail" class="btn btn-info">Add Detail</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my Index Have javascript:

```js
<script>
    $("#btnAddDetail").click(function () {
        debugger;
        var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            url: '/Sample/ViewDetail',
            //data:  $('#form1').serialize(),
            data: JSON.stringify(model),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            datatype: 'JSON',
            success: function (data) {
                // on success, post returned data in fancybox
                $.fancybox.open(data,
                    {
                        closeClickOutside: false,
                        iframe: {
                            preload: true
                        }
                    }
                    ); // fancybox
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is my Partial View:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="row-form">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.OneDetai.intLine, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.OneDetai.intLine, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-form">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.OneDetai.txtDetail1, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.OneDetai.txtDetail1, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row-form">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <button type="submit" id="btnAddLine" class="btn btn-info">Add Detail</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new SampleViewModels());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ViewDetail(SampleViewModels obj)
    {
        return PartialView("AddDetail", obj);
    }

    public ActionResult AddDetail(SampleViewModels obj)
    {
        obj.Detail.Add(obj.OneDetail);

        return View("Index", obj);
    }
```

The idea is: In order to add new detail, I have to click btnAddDetail. And it will open popup. I have to fill the popup and click btnAddLine in child form. And the data will be appear in datatable.

The question is, how I can send my Parent Model to Child model using ajax?
When the button btnAddDetail in Index triggered, I tried to send my model in JSON, but its always send the FIRST STATE of my model. If I set value in Field 1 and Field 2, and press btnAddDetail, my ViewDetail Controller always get null model. Field1 = null, Field2 = null.

I've tried data:  $('#form1').serialize(), to send my Model, It won't send my Detail Model. It just send my Header model.

Is there any way to send my Model to partial view, and send it back to my parent view?

Please help me, I haven't find any solution yet.

Thank you.

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
```

will not work, you will always get null...

if you have to make ajax post, you should do this to get values

for textbox values give them id and set your json

```
      var model = { 
                    "Header": {
                    "intID": 0,
                     "txtField1": $("#id-textField1").val(),
                     "txtField2": $("#id-textField2").val(),
                    },
                     "Detail": [],
                     "OneDetai": {
                                   "intID": 0,
                                    "intLine": 0,
                                    "txtDetail1": null
                                  }
                    }
```

Comment: Now my code work like a magic. So if I want to pass model via ajax, I have to create JSON manually? no shortcut function?

Comment: Actualy the thing is when you are posting Ajax, in your model you do not have the edited value, you have to make form submit post for that.Thats why we set values manually with jquery.if you would have the values in your model, your shortcut function could work